# Assign different data into fields based on the datetime

Tags: python

am doing an exercise and working to sort a dictionary of items by date. Example of dict:

```
 [
{"emp_id": 1, "working": "Now", "start_work": datetime.datetime(..), "end_work": datetime.datetime()},
{"emp_id": 1, "working": "Now", "start_work": datetime.datetime(..), "end_work": datetime.datetime()},
{"emp_id": 1, "working": "Now", "start_work": datetime.datetime(..), "end_work": ""}] ->previous
```

A new field is added to the list,

```
[{"emp_id": 1, "working": "Now", "start_work": datetime.datetime(..), "end_work": ""}] -> new field
```

My question is the new field, working should be Now, the previous [Now] should be [Was Working] and other two fields must be [Worked]. I am doing this in Python, to check based on the start_work and end_work, but I have no idea how can I check the previous row to assign the working to [Was working].. is someone will be able to give me any ideas? Working this to do in Python

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your list is already sorted by the `end_work` field, so you really only have to worry about each `dict`'s position in the list. Negative indices come in handy.

```
employees = [...]  # The original list
employees.append({...})  # Add the new employees
employees[-2]["working"] = "Was Working"  # Update the most recent previous employee
for emp in employees[:-3]:  # Update all other old employees
    emp["working"] = "Worked"
```

If that's not the case, you can *make* it the case easily.

```
employees.sort(key=lambda x: x["end_work"])
# Now add new employee and update previous employees
```